# Showing sequence convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing, solution-verification

Let $\{a_n\}$ for $n \geq 1$ be a sequence of real numbers defined by the recurrence relation $a_1 > 3$ and $\frac{a_{n+1} \cdot (a_n + 1)}{a_n + 9} = 1$. Prove that

(i) $\{a_{2n}\}$ for $n \geq 1$ is increasing and bounded above.

(ii) $\{a_{2n - 1}\}$ for $n \geq 1$ is decreasing and bounded below.

(iii) If $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{2n} = s$ and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{2n-1} = t$ then $s = t$ (in other words, both sequences converge to the same number), and then deduce that $\{a_n\}$ converges to $3$.

My attempt:

(i) You can see that $a_{2n} = \frac{a_{2n-1}+9}{a_{2n-1}+1}$.

Also, a careful look would imply that it is bounded above by $3$, which can be shown by using induction:

Goal. Show that $a_{2n} \leq 3$ $\forall n\geq 1$.

Base. Suppose $n = 1$. You will see that $a_{2} - 3 = \frac{a_{1}+9}{a_{1}+1} - 3 = \frac{-2a_1 + 6}{a_{1}+1}$. But the denominator is bigger than $0$ and the numerator is less than $0$ because $a_1 > 3$. This shows that $a_{2} - 3 \leq 0$ and $a_{2} \leq 3$.

Inductive. Assume that $a_{2n} \leq 3$. We show that $a_{2(n+1)} \leq 3$.

$$a_{2n + 2} - 3 = \frac{a_{2n+1}+9}{a_{2n+1}+1} - 3 = \frac{\frac{a_{2n} + 9}{a_{2n} + 1} + 9}{\frac{a_{2n} + 9}{a_{2n} + 1} + 1} - 3 = \frac{5a_{2n} + 9}{a_{2n} + 5} - 3 = \frac{2a_{2n} - 6}{a_{2n} + 5} \leq 0$$

Therefore $a_{2n}$ is bounded above by $3$.

Goal. Show that $a_{2n} \leq a_{2(n+1)}$ $\forall n\geq 1$.

Base. Suppose $n = 1$. Then $a_{2} \leq 3$ so

$$a_{2} - a_{4} = a_{2} - \frac{5a_{2} + 9}{a_{2} + 5} = \frac{a_{2}^2 - 9}{a_{2} + 5} \leq 0$$

Inductive. Assume that $a_{2n} \leq a_{2n+2}$. We show that $a_{2n+2} \leq a_{2n + 4}$.

$$a_{2n + 2} - a_{2n + 4} =a_{2n + 2} - \frac{a_{2n+3}+9}{a_{2n+3}+1} = a_{2n + 2} - \frac{\frac{a_{2n+2} + 9}{a_{2n+2} + 1} + 9}{\frac{a_{2n+2} + 9}{a_{2n+2} + 1} + 1}  = a_{2n + 2} - \frac{5a_{2n+2} + 9}{a_{2n+2} + 5} = \frac{a_{2n+2}^2 - 9}{a_{2n+2} + 5} \leq 0$$

This follows from the fact that $a_{2n + 2} \leq 3$ as shown in the bounded above induction proof.

(ii) You can see that $a_{2n-1} = \frac{a_{2n-2}+9}{a_{2n-2}+1}$.

As before it looks to me that the $a_{2n-1}$ is bounded below by $3$. Once again this can be shown by using induction:

Goal. Show that $a_{2n-1} \geq 3$ $\forall n\geq 1$.

Base. Suppose $n = 1$ then $a_{1} > 3$ (this has been directly given in the problem).

Inductive. Assume that $a_{2n-1} \geq 3$. We show that $a_{2(n+1)-1} \geq 3$.

$$a_{2n + 1} - 3 = \frac{a_{2n}+9}{a_{2n}+1} - 3 = \frac{\frac{a_{2n-1} + 9}{a_{2n-1} + 1} + 9}{\frac{a_{2n-1} + 9}{a_{2n-1} + 1} + 1} - 3 = \frac{5a_{2n-1} + 9}{a_{2n-1} + 5} - 3 = \frac{2a_{2n-1} - 6}{a_{2n-1} + 5} \geq 0$$

Goal. Show that $a_{2n-1} \geq a_{2n+1}$ $\forall n\geq 1$.

Base. Suppose $n = 1$. It is clear that $a_{1} > 3$ and $a_3 = \frac{5a_{1} + 9}{a_{1} + 5}$. So

$$a_{1} - a_{3} = a_{1} - \frac{5a_{1} + 9}{a_{1} + 5} = \frac{a_{1}^2 - 9}{a_{1} + 5} > 0$$

Inductive. Assume that $a_{2n-1} \geq a_{2n+1}$. We show that $a_{2n+1} \geq a_{2n + 3}$.

$$a_{2n + 1} - a_{2n + 3} =a_{2n + 1} - \frac{a_{2n+2}+9}{a_{2n+2}+1} = a_{2n + 1} - \frac{\frac{a_{2n+1} + 9}{a_{2n+1} + 1} + 9}{\frac{a_{2n+1} + 9}{a_{2n+1} + 1} + 1}  = a_{2n + 1} - \frac{5a_{2n+1} + 9}{a_{2n+1} + 5} = \frac{a_{2n+1}^2 - 9}{a_{2n+1} + 5} \geq 0$$

This follows from the fact that $a_{2n + 1} \geq 3$ as shown in the bounded below induction proof.

(iii) From the previous parts, it is clear that the two sequences $a_{2n}$ and $a_{2n-1}$ converge to some limit. Let $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{2n} = s$ and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{2n-1} = t$.

$$s = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{2n} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{2(n+1)} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{5a_{2n} + 9}{a_{2n} + 5} = \frac{5s + 9}{s + 5}$$

$s^2 = 9 \implies s = 3$ or $s = -3$.

$$t = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{2n-1} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{2n+1} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{5a_{2n-1} + 9}{a_{2n-1} + 5} = \frac{5t + 9}{t + 5}$$

$t^2 = 9 \implies t = 3$ or $t = -3$.

But $s, t > 0$? (not sure about this).

So $s = t = 3$.

Since two subsequences of $\{a_{n}\}$ converge to the same number $3$, $\{a_{n}\}$ must also converge to $3$ (not sure about this either).

QED.

Is all this correct? I am not sure if my reasoning that $\{a_{n}\}$ converges to $3$ is correct. I was told by somebody that I should "consider expressing $a_{n+2}$ as a function of $a_{n}$ and show that $a_{2} < 3$." Not sure how that would work though.

Any assistance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

Let $$f(x)=\frac{x+9}{x+1}=1+\frac{8}{x+1}$$

$$g(x)=f(f(x))=\frac{5x+9}{x+5}$$

If $ a_{2n}=v_n$, we have
$$v_{n+1}=g(v_n)$$

So, if $ (v_n) $ goes to $ L $, then by continuity
$$g(L)=L=\frac{5L+9}{L+5}$$
and
$$L=\pm 3$$

the same for $ (a_{2n+1})$.

Comment: What exactly does this show?

Comment: @Kraftsman It shows that $\lim a_{2n}=\lim a_{2n+1}=3$

Comment: But why not $-3$? Also what about deducing that $\{a_n\}$ converges to $3$?

Comment: @Kraftsman The sequence is positive (By induction).

Comment: Ok, is my attempt of showing this wrong then?

Comment: Correct but too long.

Comment: I see. One last thing: Does it automatically follow that if $a_{2n}$ and $a_{2n-1}$ converge to $3$, then $a_n$ converges to $3$? Would you need to show that these are the only subsequences of $\{a_n\}$?

Comment: @Kraftsman No, you don't need. it is a well-known result. If $\lim a_{2n}=\lim a_{2n+1}=L $ then $a_n\to L$.